# Separating source variable and parameter

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem that sub parameter changes **source variable**.

```
Public LEDScripts(9, 9, 9, 27) As List(Of LEDStructure)    
Sub DoWork(x As Integer, y As Integer, nowChain As Integer)
    Dim nowQue = LEDScripts(nowChain, x, y, LED_Index(nowChain, x, y)) 'Copy data from global variable.

    PrepareToQueue(nowQue) ' Call 'PrePareToQueue' method with a list of scripts to be runned.
End Sub

Private Sub PrepareToQueue(LEDList As List(Of LEDStructure))


    Dim ToBeRemoved As New List(Of LEDStructure)
    ToBeRemoved.Add(LEDList(0))
    ToBeRemoved.Add(LEDList(1))
    For Each tmpItem In ToBeRemoved
        LEDList.Remove(tmpItem) 'When it works, <Public LEDScripts(,,,)> changes!
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I **separate** `LEDList` and `LEDScripts(,,,)`?

I am using VS 2017, maybe it is a bug of Visual Basic 2017..?
+ I also tried "ByVal"

Comment: That's how reference types work. It works just how real life works. If you lend me a glass and I break the glass, would you expect your glass to remain unbroken? Of course not. So, if you pass a collection into a method and the method changes the collection, why would you expect your collection to remain unchanged? There's only one collection. If you want a change to a collection to not affect a collection then they have to be different collections, i.e. you need to create a copy of your collection and pass that in. You can then change the copy as much as you like.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I also tried a way to create temporary variable but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you create another variable or 100 other variables. Reference types (classes) always point to the same object. Just because you put the glass in a box and give it to jmcilhinney that doesn't change the fact that you'll get a broken glass back if he breaks it.

Comment: Creating another variable is of no use.  You need to create another object.  I doubt that you need a deep copy, i.e. a new `List` object that contains copies of the items. All you need is a shallow copy, i.e. a new `List` that contains the same items. That can be done simply by calling `ToList` on the original `List`.